# Take multiply slices in numpy/pytorch

Tags: numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a big one dimensional array `X.shape = (10000,)`, and a vector of indices `y = [0, 7, 9995]`.

I would like to get a matrix with rows

```
[
 X[0 : 100],
 X[7 : 107],
 concat(X[9995:], X[:95]),
]
```

That is, slices of length 100, starting at each index, with wrap-around.

I can do that with a python loop, but I'm wondering if there's a smarter batched way of doing it in pytorch or numpy, since my arrays can be quite large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple, actually.

1. For each element `E` in `y`, create a range from `E` to `E + 100`
2. Concatenate all the ranges horizontally
3. Modulo the resulting array by the length of `X`

```
indexes = np.hstack([np.arange(v, v + 100) for v in y]) % X.shape[0]
```

Output:

```
>>> indexes
array([   0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,
         11,   12,   13,   14,   15,   16,   17,   18,   19,   20,   21,
         22,   23,   24,   25,   26,   27,   28,   29,   30,   31,   32,
         33,   34,   35,   36,   37,   38,   39,   40,   41,   42,   43,
         44,   45,   46,   47,   48,   49,   50,   51,   52,   53,   54,
         55,   56,   57,   58,   59,   60,   61,   62,   63,   64,   65,
         66,   67,   68,   69,   70,   71,   72,   73,   74,   75,   76,
         77,   78,   79,   80,   81,   82,   83,   84,   85,   86,   87,
         88,   89,   90,   91,   92,   93,   94,   95,   96,   97,   98,
         99,    7,    8,    9,   10,   11,   12,   13,   14,   15,   16,
         17,   18,   19,   20,   21,   22,   23,   24,   25,   26,   27,
         28,   29,   30,   31,   32,   33,   34,   35,   36,   37,   38,
         39,   40,   41,   42,   43,   44,   45,   46,   47,   48,   49,
         50,   51,   52,   53,   54,   55,   56,   57,   58,   59,   60,
         61,   62,   63,   64,   65,   66,   67,   68,   69,   70,   71,
         72,   73,   74,   75,   76,   77,   78,   79,   80,   81,   82,
         83,   84,   85,   86,   87,   88,   89,   90,   91,   92,   93,
         94,   95,   96,   97,   98,   99,  100,  101,  102,  103,  104,
        105,  106, 9995, 9996, 9997, 9998, 9999,    0,    1,    2,    3,
          4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,   11,   12,   13,   14,
         15,   16,   17,   18,   19,   20,   21,   22,   23,   24,   25,
         26,   27,   28,   29,   30,   31,   32,   33,   34,   35,   36,
         37,   38,   39,   40,   41,   42,   43,   44,   45,   46,   47,
         48,   49,   50,   51,   52,   53,   54,   55,   56,   57,   58,
         59,   60,   61,   62,   63,   64,   65,   66,   67,   68,   69,
         70,   71,   72,   73,   74,   75,   76,   77,   78,   79,   80,
         81,   82,   83,   84,   85,   86,   87,   88,   89,   90,   91,
         92,   93,   94])
```

Now just use index `X` with that:

```
X[indexes]
```

Comment: So much simpler than I had imagined! Thanks! Do you know if the result is based on views, or if the data is actually collected? Maybe if I used `range` instead of `np.arange` I will never have to allocate an actual matrix of the size.

Comment: Nevermind, then the modulo trick won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of user17242583's answer that doesn't use a python loop:

```
N, BS, S = 10000, 1000, 100
X = np.random.randn(N)
h = np.random.randint(N, size=(BS,))
```

```
indexes = (h[..., None] + np.arange(S)) % N
result = X[indexes]
```

In pytorch I also found another solution using [unfold](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.unfold.html):

```
wrapped = torch.cat((X, X[:S-1]))
strides = wrapped.unfold(dimension=0, size=S, step=1)
result = strides[h]
```

But I haven't done experiments to see which one is more efficient yet.